# INNODB size shrink

Tags: mysql, innodb

I use very big innodb tables.

When I delete a data size does not shrink from the table.
What should I do for the reduction of crush syndrome delete data?

Answer (score 1):

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` won't shrink the *disk* size of the table unless you have`innodb_file_per_table=ON`;

If you did not already have it `ON`, turning it on will only increase disk usage.  This is because you will be moving that table out of `ibdata1` without doing anything to shrink `ibdata1`.

The only way to shrink `ibdata1` is to dump all tables, remove ibdata1, then reload all tables.  (Yuck!)

Answer (score 0):

Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE yourtablenameHERE;` in this case:

> After doing substantial insert, update, or delete operations on an InnoDB table that has its own .ibd file because it was created with the innodb_file_per_table option enabled. The table and indexes are reorganized, and disk space can be reclaimed for use by the operating system.

In the future when in doubt just [google it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html).